# Refine extended interface on switch case?

Tags: typescript

How can I refine (narrow) an interface extending a base one using a switch case in TypeScript?

```
interface X {
  type: string;
}

interface A extends X {
  type: 'a';
  a: number;
}

interface B extends X {
  type: 'b';
  b: string;
}

function processX<T extends X>(x: T) {
  switch (x.type) {
    case 'a':
      x.a; // Access 'a' property
      break;
    case 'b':
      x.b; // Access 'b' property
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: A discriminated union works right off the bat: [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgBrIN4FgBQzlgCeADhAFzIDOYUoA5gNy4C+uuoksiKAgshAA9IIACaU0mXPiKkKAcjhymeZHAogArgFsARtGWsc7cNHhJkAIX5CIo8emwqZ5ZHJ1KpyHRWq0QjFjYcGA0QBDBgAHsQZGIoSKRKSgAKAQoeAB8LAEpJFUoAd2AwBAALZFSAOmdcx3x8BDhKFAU5Mk965AFKuAZkAHp+5B4ERPFW2PjSKCIO+p0oCDgAa2VOxubXd3aVTu6dPsHh0YgkrblJyOnZ3fnFlbXkQ2YgA) Are you sure you really need this via generics?

Comment: You can use a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-func.html#discriminated-unions) like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NBYVDw). If that answers your question, I can write it up as one — if not, what did I miss?

Comment: I would like not to maintain the union

Comment: @FezVrasta The `switch` statement will narrow the Union to either `A` or `B` automatically and the Union won't maintain.

Comment: "I would like not to maintain the union".  How do you expect TypeScript to know that `x.a` or `x.b` exists if you don't mention `A | B` in your definition of `processX`?  TypeScript's types are *structural*; I can call `processX({type: "a"})` without error, and there is no `a` property.  You'll need to maintain the union somehow.  You could possibly make less redundant by doing something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WGYXkN) (the union is *computed* from the `Mappings` type).  Does that meet your needs? (If so I'll write up an answer.)  If not, what am I missing?

Comment: But since TypeScript isn't Swift, it's not particularly relevant.  Structural type systems work differently from nominal type systems.  TypeScript's type system is structural, and presumably Swift's isn't.  So does this + my prev comment fully address the question yet? Or am I still missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

You can optimize the Typescript for that

```
type ExtendsType = {
    a : {type : 'a' , a : number};
    b : {type : 'b' , b : string};
}

function getValue<T extends keyof ExtendsType>(input : ExtendsType[T]) {
       switch (input.type) {
        case 'a':
            input.a
            break;
       
        case 'b':
            input.b
            break;
        default : 
            break;
       } 
}

getValue<'a'>({type : 'a' , a : 2})
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogHsCA7AJgZwCrmgXigbwCgoSoBDKALgNEiqgHIyGoAac+pAVwFsAjCACcAvgG5ipPvXy1o1Bnxbsp1NMEEBLJAHMxhYYUIAzLkgDGwDQHskUbRGAA1MgBsuEADwYoEBMnRQANYQIFZGsH6omNgAfAAUWmBcwPTwiFFYkADaGAC6AJQEEqSkaADuGsBmABZQCUhJwAB0soVEJSVmZGjQTAyUxR0liclNZINDJHyCEGSB4pNQE6RdPYyKA4vDDaN8y0PTs-P7UCgQRmRcLinUJyWHcwuTwksGhPZOru4effEy2PQ+mwONQAEzCfJAA)